# How can I Determine Date of Import from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, web, joomla, timestamp

I uploaded a joomla website to my database some time ago.  Now I would like to know what the exact date is that I uploaded the website.  Is there a way to find this out in the database?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick way is to check the `create_time` or `update_time` when you execute this command:

```
show table  status;
```

like the following example:

```
+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name               | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length  | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| a_table            | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |    2 |             60 |         120 |  281474976710655 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2011-09-08 18:26:38 | 2011-11-07 20:38:28 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
```

Comment: Awesome answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is another way to go about this but you can probably look inside the "data" folder and see the creation date of the mysql data files.